# Is it possible to apply CSS only to first letter of first paraphraph but only if paraphraph first child is text vs an element such as span?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to make `B` red in the following snippet.

I am using [react-markdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-markdown) to render HTML from markdown so, unfortunately, I can’t use HTML attributes.

```css
p:first-of-type::first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>Aa</span>
  </p>
  <p>
    Bb
  </p>
  <p>
    Cc
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: JQuery has a 'has' selector, I don't think css has it.

Comment: @PoulBak css has a `has` selector but no browser supports it yet.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Answer (score 3):

The reason you cannot set `F` to be non-bold is because `first-letter` does not apply to inline elements.

You can demonstrate this easily by looking at the following snippet.  The `span` is displayed as a block element and then correctly removes the bold from the first-letter:

```css
p::first-letter {
  font-weight: bold;
}

p > span {
  display: block;
}

p > span::first-letter {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>
      Foo
    </span>
  </p>
  <p>
    Bar
  </p>
</div>
```

The reason is described further in the [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter):

> The ::first-letter CSS pseudo-element applies styles to the first
>   letter of the first line of a block-level element, but only when not
>   preceded by other content (such as images or inline tables).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I needed `first-of-type` to target only the first occurrence. I updated my question.